# Pass this and comma separated value as arguments to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a function that's create buttons dynamically, and onclick I Pass some arguments from click event to function .
the arguments that's I passed is: this and the second is a comma separated string .
my problem is when I passed this arguments I got this error:

> Unexpected end of input

that's the button:

```
<button class="btnCustom" onclick="getCustomItems(this, ' + CustomIDs + ')" type="button">...</button>

CustomIDs ="3,4,5";
```

and the function:

```
function getCustomItems(e, CustomIDs) {
    var IDs = CustomIDs ;
}
```

How can I pass a comma separated `this` object and `CustomIDs` as arguments to function?

Comment: believe it would look like `onclick="getCustomItems(this,CustomIDs)"`, if your CustomerIDs is a variable

Comment: custom IDs will change in every button created so it's not static

Comment: If it's a string, the use `onclick="getCustomItems(this,'CustomIDs')"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Ids are getting generated dynamically, try to set your customIds as an attribute on that button, and simply just pass 'this' as keyword in your function, and inside your function fetch your ids from attribute using this.

```
  <button class="btnCustom" onclick="getCustomItems(this)" customIDs="3,4,5"  type="button">...</button>


 function getCustomItems(e) {
      var customIDs= e.getAttribute('customIDs');
      console.log(customIds);
       //3,4,5   
      var ids= customIds.split(',');
       console.log(ids);
       //[3,4,5]
      }
```

Comment: I hope it is useful, Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're currently passing a string `+ CustomIDs +` into your function - try a variable:

```
onclick="getCustomItems(this, CustomIDs)"
```

Comment: CustomIDs  is not static it's will change dynamically in every button created

Comment: Yeah but you are always passing the same literal string

Comment: you mean to set CustomIDs as global?

Comment: You can also try to use template literals ` ``getCustomItems(this,${CustomIDs})`` `    using backticks

Comment: You mean \`${CustomIDs}\` @Drusto.

Comment: exactly @JackBashford

Comment: Sorry, fixed comment @Drusto.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the variable of an Id and pass it to the function as a variable

`var CustomIDs='my id custom'`

`<button class="btnCustom" onclick="getCustomItems(this, CustomIDs)" type="button"></button>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: you mean to set  CustomIDs as global?

Comment: @RawanMansour i don't know your implementation and how you want to change the custom id, but if you can declare as global and edit it, it will work

Comment: i do that , it's return the last value that's set to the variable  CustomIDs

Comment: if you want to comma-separated, i think is better to use an array, or if you use a string you will need to use a regex to split it. In your code you are not passing CustomIDs, you are passing `'+CustomIDs+` (a string)

Comment: yes I want to pass it as string and in the function I  will split it as an array

Comment: If you want to pass a string, and your CustomIDs is defined as `var customIDs='3,4,5` you only need to use ``getCustomItems(this, CustomIDs)``
you are passing a string with '+CustomIDs+' as content in the code you provided

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

`onclick="getCustomItems(this, \'' + CustomIDs + '\')"`